How to Handle Flavor-Based Builds for iOS in Flutter When Using a Single main.dart?
I am currently working on a Flutter project where I have six flavors for two variants: Free and Pro. Each flavor corresponds to different environments like dev, uat, and prod.
Initially, I had separate main.dart files for each flavor, such as:

main_free_dev.dart
main_free_uat.dart
main_free_prod.dart
main_pro_dev.dart
main_pro_uat.dart
main_pro_prod.dart

However, I learned about using the --flavor option in Flutter to streamline this process and manage everything with a single main.dart file.
Using the --flavor flag, I pass the flavor name from the command line. For example:
flutter run --flavor freeDev

In this setup, I handle flavor-based resource assignments and other flavor-specific logic within the main.dart file by checking the appFlavor variable, which gets the flavor name passed through the command.
This approach works perfectly for running the application on both Android and iOS.
Problem:
While I can build APKs using the GUI in Android Studio, I face issues when trying to build an IPA for iOS. Specifically:

I cannot pass the flavor name as an extra argument when archiving the build through Xcode.
I tried adding the flavor to the Xcode scheme, but the app always receives null for the appFlavor value when archiving.

This prevents me from generating a flavor-specific IPA.
What I've Tried:

Configuring the flavor in the Xcode scheme.
Running the archive using the Xcode GUI.
Both approaches result in the appFlavor being null during the build process.

Question:

How can I pass the flavor name correctly when archiving an iOS build using Xcode so that my app can handle flavor-specific logic with a single main.dart file?
Is there a proper way to configure flavors for iOS builds in Xcode to make this work seamlessly?


Use Xcode build schemes https://medium.com/@developerjamiu/mastering-flutter-flavors-tailoring-your-app-for-multiple-environments-92c65cd98638#:~:text=To%20set%20up%20flavors%20in%20iOS%2C%20we'll%20use%20build,set%20the%20target%20to%20Runner%20.

Thank for quick response, I've configured the flavor as same like this! In this article, it hasn't confirmed that how to configure the flavour based setup into the main file via appFlavor.

You can use a technique such as this to put your flavour specific details into the environment and access it from main.dart.  You can use a "run script" build phase to copy the appropriate json file based on the build configuration name

Or you can just stick with separate main files and link them to the flavour - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77271205/flutter-flavor-build-from-xcode-different-main-dart
